# How to convert std::string to WCHAR

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I need to take an std::string that I have and convert it to a WCHAR does anyone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: `wchar_t` is used to store a wide character, and `wstring` is to store a wide string. You can't convert a `string` to  `wchar_t`, do you mean that you want to convert `string` to `wstring` or to `wchar_t*`?

Comment: Just access the characters with the [] operator and cast.

Answer (score 9):

Your question is vague; `wchar_t` is used to store a wide character, and `wstring` is to store a wide string. You can't convert a `string` to `wchar_t`.

But if your aim was to convert an `std::string` to `wchar_t*`, then you need to convert your `std::string` to an `std::wstring` first, then to convert your `std::wstring` to `const wchar_t*`.

```
string narrow_string("A string");
wstring wide_string = wstring(narrow_string.begin(), narrow_string.end());
const wchar_t* result = wide_string.c_str();
```

Comment: This only works correctly with ASCII characters. In practice.

Comment: Thinking of it, it's incorrect even for ASCII, e.g. Big-5 happily overlaps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to convert from the locale encoding, since you want [wchar_t](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/html_node/The-wchar_005ft-mess.html).

Option 1, since C++11 but deprecated in C++17:

```
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744559
template<class I, class E, class S>
struct codecvt_ : std::codecvt<I, E, S> { ~codecvt_ () {} };

std::wstring to_wide (const std::string &multi) {
    return std::wstring_convert<codecvt_<wchar_t, char, mbstate_t>> {}
        .from_bytes (multi);
}
```

Option 2, widely portable:

```
std::wstring to_wide (const std::string &multi) {
    std::wstring wide; wchar_t w; mbstate_t mb {};
    size_t n = 0, len = multi.length () + 1;
    while (auto res = mbrtowc (&w, multi.c_str () + n, len - n, &mb)) {
        if (res == size_t (-1) || res == size_t (-2))
            throw "invalid encoding";

        n += res;
        wide += w;
    }
    return wide;
}
```